# java.lang.NullPointerException error in GridView making app crash

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview

I created a 2x2 grid where the first 3 grids has three(Thingspeak) charts imported from GitHub(https://github.com/MacroYau/ThingSpeakAndroid)and the fourth grid will be implemented later so for the time being I just added a blank chart in it.
I have checked out all similar questions on stackoverflow and read their answers and I have understood the error in the logcat at line 60(`chartView = (LineChartView) findViewById(R.id.chart);`) means that this id is pointing to `null` but I don't know how to solve it as `chart` is present as an `id` in my `activity_main.xml` layout.

I have used the following files: `activity_main.xml`, `main.xml`, `TempHumidity.java` and `GridViewAdapter.java`

Code snippet from `TempHumidity.java`

```
public class TempHumidity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private ThingSpeakChannel tsChannel, tsChannel1, tsChannel2;
  private ThingSpeakLineChart tsChart, tsChart1, tsChart2;
  private LineChartView chartView, chartView1, chartView2;

  GridView simpleGrid;
  int charts[] = {R.id.chart, R.id.chart1, R.id.chart2};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    simpleGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.simpleGridView); // init GridView
    // Create an object of CustomAdapter and set Adapter to GirdView
    GridViewAdapter customAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), charts);
    simpleGrid.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    // Connect to ThinkSpeak Channels
    tsChannel = new ThingSpeakChannel(377467);
    tsChannel1 = new ThingSpeakChannel(357670);
    tsChannel2 = new ThingSpeakChannel(377509);
    // Set listener for Channel feed update events
    tsChannel.setChannelFeedUpdateListener(new ThingSpeakChannel.ChannelFeedUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChannelFeedUpdated(long channelId, String channelName, ChannelFeed channelFeed) {
            // Show Channel ID and name on the Action Bar
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(channelName);
            getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Channel " + channelId);
            // Notify last update time of the Channel feed through a Toast message
            Date lastUpdate = channelFeed.getChannel().getUpdatedAt();
            Toast.makeText(TempHumidity.this, lastUpdate.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    // Fetch the specific Channel feed
    tsChannel.loadChannelFeed();

    // Create a Calendar object dated 1 minutes ago
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1);

    // Configure LineChartView
    chartView = (LineChartView) findViewById(R.id.chart); //Logcat error points here
    chartView.setZoomEnabled(false);
    chartView.setValueSelectionEnabled(true);
```

`GridViewAdapter.java`

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 private Context context;
 private final int[] charts;
 LayoutInflater inflter;

 public GridViewAdapter(Context Appcontext, int[] charts) {
    this.context = Appcontext;
    this.charts = charts;
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(Appcontext));
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null); // inflate the layout
    LineChartView cv = (LineChartView) view.findViewById(R.id.chart); // get the reference of ImageView
    return view;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return charts.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
    }


}
```

`main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<!--
-->
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/simpleGridView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:numColumns="2" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Container LinearLayout -->
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
 <!-- Row 1 -->
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1">
<lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.LineChartView
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.LineChartView
    android:id="@+id/chart1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Row 2 -->
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1">
<lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.LineChartView
    android:id="@+id/chart2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.LineChartView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`Logcat`:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.demo/com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.demo.TempHumidity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.demo.TempHumidity.onCreate(TempHumidity.java:60)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-14 17:11:28.007 23142-23146/com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.demo 
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 587K, 19% free 8887K/10932K, paused 4ms+22ms, total 114ms
```

When I run the codes(as it is in GitHub) without adding two similar charts in a `GridView`:
[image]

Currently my `activity_main.xml` layout looks like this:

[image]

Comment: "as `chart` is present as an `id` in my `activity_main.xml` layout." – The layout you're setting in `TempHumidity` would be the `main.xml` file. Are you sure you're not getting some layouts mixed up?

Comment: I am not sure about that. `activity_main.xml` is present in the `GridViewAdapter.java` file to inflate it though. I set layout as `main` in `TempHumidity` to set the `GridLayout`

Comment: Hmm, OK, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but that `findViewById()` call in `onCreate()` will only find `View`s in the layout you're passing to `setContentView()`, which is `main`, which doesn't contain `chart`, so it'll return null. Furthermore, the layout you inflate in `GridViewAdapter`'s `getView()` method is the layout for each individual item in the `GridView`. Is that what you're wanting?

Comment: I am not sure I understood what you meant to say with this "Furthermore, the layout you inflate in `GridViewAdapter`'s `getView()` method is the layout for each individual item in the `GridView` "I just simply want a 2x2 grid filled with the 3 charts in the first three grids.. Being a newbie in `android` and `java` programming, I didn't write the code from scratch so there might be some bugs out there due to some copying, pasting and editing them to suit them in my required needs of having a 2x2 grid for the charts that's why I would appreciate any modifications and suggestions.

Comment: I have understood in the first line, you pointed out `main` doesn't contain `chart` but then now do I modify this? Should I set the `GridView` layout in  `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: I really don't know. What is the `GridView` for, exactly? I mean, you already have a 2x2 of `LineChartView`s in `activity_main`.

Comment: Actually, you seem to be right. I will make the required changes by removing the `main` layout and using the `activity_main` layout in `TempHumidity.java`. I suppose the `GridViewAdapter` also won't be needed then, right?

Comment: Right. Yeah, that's starting to make sense, then. :-)

Comment: I did as you said and it worked like charm. Thanks a lot :) You can write it as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Ah, excellent! Glad to help. I'm good, though. You just had some extraneous stuff in there. Nothing really major. If you wanna call it a freebie, you can just delete this. Otherwise, feel free to post your own answer with the changes you made. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: That's nice of you.. I'll post my answer with the changes I made shortly.

Comment: Hey @MikeM., can you help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359546/mpandroidchart-showing-no-chart-data-available-when-retrieving-chart-data-from ?

Comment: Hmm, probably not. That is, I've never used either Ubidots or MPAndroidChart. About all I could suggest from a first look is to make sure that `onDataReady()` is actually running, and that it's delivering a non-empty result. Beyond that, I'm not sure. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, it's fine. Thanks for looking into that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike M. in the comments pointed out that the `chart` id is not present in the `main.xml` file which is the reason why it pointing to null. 
All I had to do is remove the `main.xml` file and set the layout to `activity_main.xml` in the `onCreate` method like this:
 `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` (as I have already made a 2x2 layout in it `activity_main.xml`) 
and remove the `GridViewAdapter.java`.